# Polymer 1.0 google-analytics-query: Nothing is showing up

Tags: google-analytics, polymer, polymer-1.0, google-web-component

I am trying to develop a dashboard for my client where I have to use several `google web components`. My first approach is to show up a simple `analytic query` for which I am using this:

```html
<google-analytics-query
  ids="ga:xxxxxxxx"
  metrics="ga:sessions"
  dimensions="ga:country"
  sort="-ga:sessions"
  start-date="2015-10-01"
  end-date="2015-10-31"
  max-results="5">
</google-analytics-query>
```

But nothing is visible!
I am referring to https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-analytics?active=google-analytics-query

What's going wrong?

**UPDATE**
I also tried the following code to render `google-analytics-chart` output ended up with a big white box.

```html
<google-analytics-chart
  type="area"
  ids="ga:88814676"
  metrics="ga:sessions"
  dimensions="ga:date"
  start-date="2015-10-01"
  end-date="2015-10-31"
  max-results="5">
</google-analytics-chart>
```

Comment: Are you only using google-analytics-query? Because that's a data-provider element like iron-ajax, which means that they won't display. You might have to use `google-analytics-chart` so you can see some display at least.

Comment: Initially I was trying with google-analytics-query (when I put my question) but then switched to google-analytics-chart. What I saw with google-analytics-chart is the container (where I intend to show the rendered output) was getting some width and height. But there is no display. just a big white box is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

This question as also asked on the Github repo for the `<google-analytics>` element. You can see the answer there:
https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-analytics/issues/29#issuecomment-157367824

The gist of the problem: using the `<google-analytics-chart>` element require authentication via the `<google-signin>` element in order to work.